# Understanding .then() ES6

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I ran into a bug in my code that puzzled me for a long time and am looking for some clarification.

In this code, the commented out inner promise was causing a problem. The Promise.all() at the end was continuing as soon as the setTimeout hit, not after the resolve inside the timeout.

Wrapping the async code with a promise fixes the flow problem, but why is this?

Essentially, why can't we just run normal async code in a .then() chain, an return a Promise.resolve() at the end of the async callback?

```
var asyncPromise = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Async Promise done');
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
};

var generateSignupPromises = function(qty) {
    var promiseArray = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {
        promiseArray.push(
            function() {
                return asyncPromise()
                .then(function() {
                    console.log('Before Timeout');

                  //Uncommenting this fixes the issue
                  //return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            console.log('After Timeout');
                            //resolve();
                            return Promise.resolve();
                        }, 500);
                  //})
                });
            }
        );
    }
    return promiseArray;
};

var test = generateSignupPromises(1);

Promise.all([test[0]()])
.then(function() {
    console.log('Done');
});
```

Link to running code: http://www.es6fiddle.net/imfdtuxc/

Comment: I can't really tell what you're trying to do, but a `return` inside a `setTimeout()` handler pretty much never makes much sense; nothing will pay attention to the returned value.

Comment: Pyramid of doom + plethora of anonymous functions = unreadable code + unexpected behavior.

Comment: setTimeout isn't async. It returns synchronously, causing your then() to return undefined ending that 'promise'. By adding your extra line it returns another promise that will wait until `resolve`. BTW. This is not how promises should be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why can't we just run normal async code in a .then() chain, an return a Promise.resolve() at the end of the async callback?

You perfectly can. But any value - be it a promise or whatever - being `return`ed from a plain asynchronous callback is just *ignored as usual*.

There is nothing that starting the asynchronous action inside a `then` callback changes about this, `setTimeout` just doesn't return a promise - and the `then` won't know about anything asynchronous happening that it could wait for.

If you want to return a promise from a callback and get another promise for that eventual result, it has to be a `then` callback:

```
asyncPromise()
.then(function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
//  ^^^^^^
        setTimeout(resolve, 500);
    }).then(function() {
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return Promise.resolve();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Then is a sync function so if you want to do async task inside then, you has to return a Promise.

Also, Promise.all expect an array of promises. Not an array of an array.

```
var asyncPromise = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Async Promise done');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
};

var generateSignupPromises = function(qty) {
  var promiseArray = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {
    promiseArray.push(
      function() {
        return asyncPromise()
        .then(function() {
          console.log('Before Timeout');

          //Uncommenting this fixes the issue
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('After Timeout');
            resolve();
            //return Promise.resolve();
          }, 500);
          })
        });
      }
    );
  }
  return promiseArray;
};

var test = generateSignupPromises(1);

Promise.all([test[0]()])
.then(function() {
  console.log('Done');
});
```

http://www.es6fiddle.net/imfe2sze/